# Opencv running Kmeans on output of HoughLineP(): Vector to Mat conversion?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, k-means, mat

I have been trying to run kmeans on the output of cv::HoughLinesP(). My issue comes from converting the output of HoughLinesP(), `opencv_lines`, which is an vector of `Vector<Vec4i>` into a Matrix. This sounds extremely simple and I bet it is but, I'm new to opencv and the data structures and have tried numerous things.  Here is the code I'm trying to implement.

```
HoughLinesP(image_after_canny, opencv_lines, 2, 0.05*CV_PI/180, lower_hough_prob_min_no_of_intersections_trackbar + hough_prob_min_no_of_intersections_trackbar, lower_hough_prob_min_no_of_points_trackbar + hough_prob_min_no_of_points_trackbar, lower_hough_prob_max_gap_bw_points_trackbar + hough_prob_max_gap_bw_points_trackbar);
//opencv_lines is an Nx4 opencv[0] = [x1, y1, x2, y2]

//Spatial Clustering on line endpoints
//For each frame the endpoints should not change much relative to location


//sanity checking
// Mat samples = Mat(opencv_lines);
// samples.convertTo(samples, CV_32F);
// cout << samples.dims << endl;
// cout << samples.depth() << endl;
// cout << samples.type() << endl;

//Convert the opencv_lines into a matrix for kmeas
//There must be an better way
Mat samples  = Mat(opencv_lines.size(), 4, CV_32FC1); //create a Nx4 matrix oftype 32F 
for(int r = 0; r<opencv_lines.size(); r++){
      Vec4i l_cur = opencv_lines[r];
      for(int c = 0; c<4; c ++){
        samples.at<float>(r,c) = opencv_lines[r][c];
      }
}



cout << "Running Kmeans" << endl;
cv::kmeans(opencv_lines,K,labels, TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, max_iteration, epsilone), attempts, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

The error that I receive is:

...
Detecting Lines
    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (data0.dims <= 2 && type == CV_32F && K > 0) in kmeans, file /Development/OpenCV/modules/core/src/kmeans.cpp, line 230
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Development/OpenCV/modules/core/src/kmeans.cpp:230: error: (-215) data0.dims <= 2 && type == CV_32F && K > 0 in function kmeans

```
Abort trap: 6
```

I have tried a number of ways to do this using `memecopy(samples.data, opencv_lines.data()*sizeof(float));`  and other various looping structures.

I even switched over to python implementation and ran into the same dang problem !! so Im officially stuck.

PS I know that output of hough is working properly and there are lines. 
UPDATE:
I have added some print statements and have been using the reshape() function thinking i was not satisfying the data0.dims <=2.

Here is the new edits:

```
 Mat samples  = Mat(opencv_lines.size(), 4, CV_32F); //create a Nx4 matrix oftype 32F 
    for(int r = 0; r<opencv_lines.size(); r++){
          Vec4i l_cur = opencv_lines[r];
          for(int c = 0; c<4; c ++){
            samples.at<float>(r,c) = opencv_lines[r][c];
            cout << opencv_lines[r][c] << " " ;
          }
          cout << ""<< endl;
    }
    samples=samples.reshape(1,samples.rows * 2);

    samples.convertTo(samples, CV_32F);
    cout << "M = "<< endl << " "  << samples << endl << endl;

    cout << "Running Kmeans" << endl;
    cv::kmeans(opencv_lines,K,labels, TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, max_iteration, epsilon), attempts, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

And yet the same error:

```
   Fetching Video
Initializing Parameter
Begin Playback
Frame
Generating Skeleton Image
Detecting Lines
335 471 335 112 
337 443 338 105 
339 443 339 103 
355 68 382 478 
291 479 313 162 
356 66 383 478 
436 2 533 223 
293 479 316 152 
440 3 523 195 
416 0 500 427 
359 63 383 474 
416 4 499 425 
437 0 534 223 
343 479 376 153 
427 0 525 305 
427 1 579 479 
344 478 378 153 
M = 
 [335, 471;
 335, 112;
 337, 443;
 338, 105;
 339, 443;
 339, 103;
 355, 68;
 382, 478;
 291, 479;
 313, 162;
 356, 66;
 383, 478;
 436, 2;
 533, 223;
 293, 479;
 316, 152;
 440, 3;
 523, 195;
 416, 0;
 500, 427;
 359, 63;
 383, 474;
 416, 4;
 499, 425;
 437, 0;
 534, 223;
 343, 479;
 376, 153;
 427, 0;
 525, 305;
 427, 1;
 579, 479;
 344, 478;
 378, 153]

Running Kmeans
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (data0.dims <= 2 && type == CV_32F && K > 0) in kmeans, file /Development/OpenCV/modules/core/src/kmeans.cpp, line 230
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: Development/OpenCV/modules/core/src/kmeans.cpp:230: error: (-215) data0.dims <= 2 && type == CV_32F && K > 0 in function kmeans

Abort trap: 6
```

Could someone please help clarify the input structure that is described in the documentation.

Data for clustering. An array of N-Dimensional points with float coordinates is needed. Examples of this array can be:

```
Mat points(count, 2, CV_32F);
Mat points(count, 1, CV_32FC2);
Mat points(1, count, CV_32FC2);
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points(sampleCount);
```

Comment: can you explain what you want to cluster?

Comment: For a given line that is detected, there  are multiple proposals to where the line is. So in a given frame, there may be 2 or 3 plausible set of end points that make up a line proposal. Essentially I what I want to do is apply some sort of spatial smoothing where the final endpoint is the average or cluster center of a group of points. To make it even simpler, kmeans on x,y coordinates of the endpoints.

Comment: Why are you running kmeans on "opencv_lines" instead of "samples"?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing to python implementation and using sci-kit to run a dbscan on the hough output. This way I was able to cluster the probabilistic hough outputs into different section by filter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39FJT.png) out the unwanted line segments.